# missing type specifier with extern statement

Tags: c++, winapi, extern

I know this question had been asked some times but i didnt find an solution for my problem. I am trying to init a simple Window for an D3D lateron.

I got an header with some gobal stuff:

```
#pragma once
//includes for handling the window
#include<windows.h>
#include<commctrl.h>
#include<d3d9.h>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

#include "MyApplication.h"

//constants
#define TITLE L"D3D Example"
#define WINDOW_X 350
#define WINDOW_Y 320

//Button ID's
#define ID_START 1
#define ID_CANCEL 2

//globals
extern MyApplication g_Application;

//functions
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);
```

Inside of the "main.cpp" i simply init those global.

```
#include "main.h"

MyApplication g_Application;
//mainloop starts here
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPreviousInstance,
                   LPSTR lpcmdline,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG Message; //contains messages from window
//main program loop
    while(g_Application.GetWindowStatus())
    {
//get next message from queue
        if(GetMessage(&Message,NULL,0,0))
        {
            //process dialog messages, e.g. tabs
            if(!IsDialogMessage(g_Application.GetWindowHandle(),&Message))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&Message); //translate messages
                DispatchMessage(&Message);  //dispatch message to window procedure
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and cant compile that i am getting this errors and warnings.

```
Error   1   error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'g_Application' c:\users\benjamin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\applicationproject\applicationproject\main.h    22  1   ApplicationProject
Error   2   error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   c:\users\benjamin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\applicationproject\applicationproject\main.h    22  1   ApplicationProject
Error   3   error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   c:\users\benjamin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\applicationproject\applicationproject\main.h    22  1   ApplicationProject
```

(sorry for german Error List regulary it shouldnt be like that..)

This code is close to an tutorial i am working throu and i already copy pasted the tutorial code to it but it does have the same misstake. What have i done wrong?

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `MyApplication.h` includes `main.h`, creating a circular dependency - each tries to include the other. The include guards prevent a disastrous infinite recursion, but you end up with one included before the other, and the first is unable to use names declared in the second.

In this case, you don't need the full definition of `MyApplication`, so replace

```
#include "MyApplication.h"
```

with a forward declaration

```
class MyApplication;
```

You'll still need to include the header in any source file that needs the definition of `MyApplication`.

In any case, I strongly advise you not to use global variables. Problems like these are just the first steps on a long road of pain if you do.

Comment: I do get different error out of that: `Error 1 error C2079: 'g_Application' verwendet undefiniertes class 'MyApplication' c:\users\benjamin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\applicationproject\applicationproject\main.cpp 3 1 ApplicationProject
`

Comment: @BennX: You'll need to include the header from `main.cpp`, since it's no longer being dragged in by the other header.

Comment: Thanks on that but than i need to include the header overall which makes the gobal more or less useless right. I do use the g_Application in different cpps for example the Inputhandler and so on.

Comment: @BennX: Yes, globals usually are useless, and invariably lead to problems. If you really want to keep this one, and make it magically available just by including `main.h`, then you'll have to find a way to avoid including `main.h` from `MyApplication.h`.

Comment: thanks for that advices. Yes your guess was totaly right. Thanks for the solution. I am going to avoid the global and point to the application.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this line is your problem:

```
#include "MyApplication.h";
```

Take off the semi-colon at the end, like this:

```
#include "MyApplication.h"
```

`#include` lines are preprocessor directives, so they do not need to be terminated with semi-colons (unlike C++ statements).

Comment: This just avoids the warnings.